# Display stars based on array values using showOptionDialog

Tags: java, joptionpane

What would be the best way to display each value in the array as *n* times a star in this case (using showOptionDialog)?
I was considering using a for loop, but I'm not sure where I'd fit that in the code.

Code so far:

```
int[] stars = {2,4,6};

String[] options = {"yes","no"}
int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "stars1: " + stars[0]...
                     + "\n stars2:" + stars[1]...
                     + "\n stars3:" + stars[2]...,
             "Stars", 0, 3, null, options, null);
```

Expected Output:

```
**
****
******
```

Hope this makes sense, thanks!

Comment: try writing a method that will convert a integer to a String of integer's length

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
int[] stars = {2,4,6};
String[] starsStr = new String[stars.length];
for(int i = 0;i < stars.length;i++){
    String temp = "";
    for(int j = 0; j < stars[i];j++){
       temp+="*";
    }
    starsStr[i] = temp;
}
String[] options = {"yes","no"};
int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, starsStr,
     "Stars", 0, 3, null, options, null);
```